# Removing white box around Picture box over another?

Tags: parent, picturebox, visual-c#-express-2010

I am trying to move a pictureBox2 that is in a groupBox2 container to another groupBox1.
The problem is that in that container, there is a another pictureBox1 and when I move the pictureBox2 over pictureBox1, pictureBox2 gets a white box around it.

All in all, I want to blend that pictureBox2 to pictureBox1.

Here is my code that incorporates the mouse move, up and down functionality:

```
    private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        downPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox2.Parent = this;
        pictureBox2.BringToFront();

    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {

            pictureBox2.Left += e.X - downPoint.X;
            pictureBox2.Top += e.Y - downPoint.Y;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = GetChildAtPoint(new Point(pictureBox2.Left - 1, pictureBox2.Top));

        if (c == null) c = this;
        Point newLoc = c.PointToClient(pictureBox2.Parent.PointToScreen(pictureBox2.Location));
        pictureBox2.Parent = c;
        pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pictureBox2.Location = newLoc;

        this.Refresh();
        pictureBox2.BringToFront();
    }
```

I am able to move the pictureBox2 anywhere and assign it a parent, but I can't get it to assign pictureBox1 as its parent, as it only detects the groupBox2 as its parent.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.
Vincent

Comment: I found out that it was groupBox2 that was causing the problems. Removing that made it possible to bring the one pictureBox in front of the other on the Form itself. But if there is any solution to the above mentioned, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `PictureBox1.BorderStyle` Property to `None`.